# Twitter API application-only authentication (with TweetSharp)

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I am trying to retrieve public tweets from a server-side application, using [application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) (no user context).

The following code works fine:

```
var service = new TwitterService("<consumer key>", "<consumer secret>");
service.AuthenticateWith("<access token>", "<access token secret>"); 

var options = new ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions { ScreenName = "billgates" };

foreach (var tweet in service.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(options))
    Console.WriteLine(tweet.Text);
```

However I gather from this diagram that it shouldn't be necessary to provide the access token/secret:

[image: Application-only authentication]

However when I remove the call to `AuthenticateWith`, `ListTweetsOnUserTimeline` returns null.

It is a limitation of the library, if not, how can I do it?

**EDIT**

Aas far as I can tell, this calls the [`GET statuses/user_timeline`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) method that should support application-only authentication, as per the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth):

> API methods that support this form of authentication will contain two rate limits in their documentation, one that is per user (for application-user authentication) and the other is per app (for this form of application-only authentication)

The `GET statuses/user_timeline` method has these 2 limits shown in its documentation.

Comment: any luck with this method?

Comment: For those interested, the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/issues/80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confirmed as not being supported:
https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/issues/80#issuecomment-19862455

As this project is being retired, there is no plan to add support for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this in not a limitation of the library, but limitation of the Twitter API.

As far as I know, the ListTweetsOnUserTimeline() method uses statuses/user_timeline API call.

[GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline)

As you can see, this call requires authentication.

You can try to use the Streaming API for getting statuses. I can't help you here since I have only experience with user streams, not public.

[Public streams](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public)

Besides, the TweetSharp has some problems with streams, I had to switch to Linq2Twitter library.

Comment: I think this method should support application-only auth, which I guess is it a form of authentication, hence the `Authentication: Required` (see my edits in the question).

Comment: From what I've been able to read, I don't believe you can use streams without authenticating with the user.